# php Error description: Incorrect string value: '\xF4t l'\xE9...' on insert

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am inserting data from a UTF8-general-ci table to another UTF8-general-ci table. These are articles. About 20 or 30 will not insert due to random use of French titles or phrases like " à la". The error I receive is Error description: Incorrect string value: '\xF4t l'\xE9...'.

Nothing I do seems to work, including adding

```
 mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
```

If both tables are already UTF8, what else can I do to insert these random articles with French phrases?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bytes you've quoted in your question (F4 and E9) aren't valid in UTF-8 data. Some or all of your data is probably actually ISO-8859-1 — you'll need to convert it to UTF-8 using [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) or [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

Comment: wrapping the field in utf8_encode() did indeed allow an insert. Thank you@

Comment: utf8_encode($string) worked for me.  mb_convert_encoding($string) did not.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Jason If it "worked", then there are other encoding problems in your application which you need to fix. (You will find that some other Unicode characters, like emoji, won't work at all.)

Comment: I agree with your statement Duskwuff.  Unfortunately, the data comes from a Wordpress website, which I don't have control over.  The user likes to copy/paste from various sources, and many times an apostrophe turns into a diamond with a question mark in it.  The data is stored as a CSV which is imported into my application, which is when the error arises.  I tried a regex to remove the bad character, but it didn't work. Using utf8_encode($string) before the data is converted to CSV allows the import to continue, but the apostrophe in question is still converted to a (utf8) question mark.

Answer (score 6):

Try this with **utf8_encode()**;

```
        $sql = "INSERT INTO table (col1)
        VALUES ('".utf8_encode($input_variable)."')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
        {
            echo "Inserted!";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
```