# How to save accents in database from php controller on laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, character-encoding

I have an issue and I've wasted enough time on it already.

I'm writing the name of the files in a  directory into my database, but some files have special characters in them, like accents, and I keep getting this error when I try to write.

> SQLSTATE[ HY000 ]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value.

I've already tried  changing the charset of  my database and its tables but it's still the same.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828910/php-error-description-incorrect-string-value-xf4t-l-xe9-on-insert). probably character encoding is wrong

Comment: Wow Regolith I wish I would've made this question before! Your suggestion really helped me so much. All I had to do is to  encode my variable like :      $ value=utf_encode ($value). Thank you so much!

Comment: What encoding is in your application?  Check the "best practice" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored .  If that does not help enough, then provide info on the things that it mentions.